# How do I convert each line of my text file into a dictionary entry?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm fairly new to Python. 
At the moment, I have a text file called 'action_table2.txt' where the contents look like this:

```
1: Goals
2: Dreams
3: Environment
4: Outside
5: Inside
6: Reality
7: Allies
8: Enemies
9: Evil
10: Good
...
```

I want to turn each line into a key:value entry in a dictionary called action_table2, but at this rate, the only way I know how to do it is to copy and paste the table into python, then manually type quotation marks outside of each 'value' and then manually add a comma after each one. This is extremely tedious (especially since I'm doing this for multiple tables).

I've tried printing out each line with formatting so I could then copy and paste it already formatted the way I want, but I couldn't see how to add quotation marks, just commas or extra text.

I've also tried this code:

```
action_table2 = {}
with open('action_table2.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        key, value = line.strip().split(':')
        action_table2[key] = (value)
```

but when I try to retrieve the key, I get a key error. 
(This is what it looks like when I try to retrieve it:)

```
import random
print(action_table2[random.randint(1,100)])
```

Comment: Try `action_table2[int(key)] = value`  (note that there is no point for the parentheses around `value`).

Comment: Please don't post such large amounts of data! You could get away with, say, 5 items and the question would remain the same.

Comment: Ok, ten items is good as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the keys from strings to integers.

```
action_table2 = {}
with open('action_table2.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        key, value = line.strip().split(':')
        action_table2[int(key)] = (value)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the type returned by `rand.randint` is different from the type of your key. You can do two things:

#### 1) Cast dictionary keys in integers:

```
import random 

action_table2 = {}
with open('action_table2.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        key, value = line.strip().split(': ')
        action_table2[int(key)] = value

print(action_table2[random.randint(1, len(action_table2))])
```

#### 2) Cast the value of the key returned from `random.randint` in string:

```
import random 

action_table2 = {}
with open('action_table2.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        key, value = line.strip().split(': ')
        action_table2[key] = value

print(action_table2[str(random.randint(1, len(action_table2)))])
```

#### **Note**:

- In both cases I replaced the `split(":")` with `split(": ")` to avoid having a space as the first character of the value
- If you prefer you can also solve your problem using dict comprehension:

  `action_table2 = {s.split(':')[0]: s.strip().split(': ')[1] for s in f}`